# Select Insert substituting local variable for a column

Tags: sql-server, variables, select, insert

I want to Insert records from one table into another like

```
Insert into table2([column1], [column2], [column3])  
select column1, column2, column3  
from table1
```

however instead of all three values coming from table one I would like to insert a specific value stored in a variable.  I Think it would look something like this

```
declare @variable int
set @variable = 2

Insert into table2([column1], [column2], [column3]) 
select @variable, column2, column3  
from table1
```

In this way every row from table one would be inserted into table two with the only difference being every value in column one would be 2.

Is this possible without using a cursor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you've done it is correct:

```
INSERT INTO table2 ([column1], [column2], [column3])
SELECT @variable, column2, column3
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 1):

what you have should work just fine

```
declare @variable int 
set @variable = 2

Insert into table2([column1], [column2], [column3]) 
select @variable, column2, column3
from table1
```